# R Removing duplicate columns based on variability

Tags: r, variables, dplyr, duplicates, naming

I have a very large dataset with multiple duplicated column names (the values within the columns are different). I would like to remove the columns with duplicate names and lower variability. My problem is I have too many of these duplicate variables to do this manually. One path I am trying to to use `read.csv()`, which automatically adds '.1' to the duplicate column name, then make a vector of the variability of all the columns and try to work with that.

```
df<-data.frame("A"=c(1,5,10), "A.1"=c(2,2,2), "C"=c(1,5,10), "C.1"=c(2,2,2), "C.2"=c(2,5,10))
v<-lapply(df, function(x) var(x))
```

Is there a way to filter out duplicates based on variability when I am importing the dataset? Again, the biggest problem is that I have too many duplicates to do this manually. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Combining techniques from base R and tidyverse:

```
# calculate variance for each column
dvar <- apply(df, 2, var)
library(tidyverse)
# create data frame with column names
# "grouped" column names and variance
# find column with highest variance
keep_names <- data.frame(names = names(dvar),
           grouping = gsub("[[:punct:]][0-9]", "", names(dvar)),
           vals = dvar) %>%
  group_by(grouping) %>%
  slice_max(vals) %>%
  pull(names)
# pull data
df[keep_names]

#    A  C
# 1  1  1
# 2  5  5
# 3 10 10
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame("A"=c(1,5,10), "A.1"=c(2,2,2), "C"=c(1,5,10), "C.1"=c(2,2,2), "C.2"=c(2,5,10))
df["var",] <-apply(df, 2, var)
nrow(df)
df <- df[,which(df["var",] < 20)]
df
```

Imagine "20" being your threshold. I used apply here an appended it to the dataframe.

```
    A.1 C.1      C.2
1     2   2  2.00000
2     2   2  5.00000
3     2   2 10.00000
var   0   0 16.33333
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose a new version using exponential search and data.table power.

This a function I implemented in dataPreparation package.

**The function**

`dataPreparation::which_are_bijection`

```
which_are_in_double(df)
```

Which return 3 and 4 the columns that are duplicated in your example

**Build a data set with wanted dimensions for performance tests**

```
df<-data.frame("A"=c(1,5,10), "A.1"=c(2,2,2), "C"=c(1,5,10), "C.1"=c(2,2,2), "C.2"=c(2,5,10))
for (i in 1:20){
  df = rbind(df, df)  
}
```

Which result in a `data.frame` of size `(3 145 728, 5)`

**The benchmark**
To perform the benchmark, I use the library `rbenchmark` which will reproduce each computations 100 times

```
benchmark(
  which_are_in_double(df, verbose=FALSE),
  apply(df, 2, var) == 0
)
```

```
                                      test replications elapsed relative
2                   apply(df, 2, var) == 0          100  38.298    3.966
1 which_are_in_double(df, verbose = FALSE)          100   9.656    1.000
```

So which are bijection is 4 time faster than other proposed solution. The nice thing is that the bigger the `data.frame` the performance will be even more interesting.